# Why is dribble producing an empty file?

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl, slime

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

By the end of chapter 9, the author shows the *dribble* tool.
He shows the following:

[image]
[image]

I tried to reproduce the commands presented by the author. Considering the inputs, the only difference was the fact that I put a different location to save the file. In my environment, I did:

```
CL-USER> (dribble "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/symbolic-computation/teste-tool.log")
; No value
CL-USER> (cons 2 nil)
(2)
CL-USER> '(is driblle really working?)
(IS DRIBLLE REALLY WORKING?)
CL-USER> "is dribble useful at all?"
"is dribble useful at all?"
CL-USER> (dribble)
; No value
```

The file was indeed created:

```
$ readlink -f teste-tool.log 
/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/symbolic-computation/teste-tool.log
```

Note that I did not get messages such as "Now recording in file --location---" in the REPL while I was typing. But this may vary according to the Lisp implementation.

The big surprise was that, unfortunately, the file was empty. Thus, dribble did not work as expected.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `dribble` will probably do what you expect if you run an SBCL session in a terminal window. Slime tinkers with the I/O streams, and that is probably the culprit here. I don't know if there is a simple way to get the Slime REPL to behave in this instance.

Comment: Related: [flight-recorder](https://github.com/vseloved/flight-recorder) (similar, records more data, based on a HTTP server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, by default, within Slime I don't think this works.
2. It *will* work within the SBCL Repl:

```lisp
➜ sbcl
This is SBCL 2.0.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (dribble "dribble-test.lisp")
* (* 8 5)

40
* "Will this work?"

"Will this work?"
* (dribble)

* %
```

Which can be confirmed:

```sh
➜ cat dribble-test.lisp
* (* 8 5)

40
* "Will this work?"

"Will this work?"
* (dribble)
```

3. Saving "REPL history" seems less useful with Slime IMO because of all the "non-REPL evaluation" that you do by e.g. selecting a function or an expression or region and evaluating that in the REPL.
4. To *actually* save and view history within Slime, see `slime-repl-save-history` and associated functions; you can even *merge histories from independent Repls* if you so choose :-)